# Why does this (generally) false equality hold (almost) 272 times in a row

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The equality 
$(*)\lceil \frac{n^2}{1681}\rceil= 
\lfloor \frac{(n+1)^2}{1682}\rfloor$
is false for most natural numbers $n$ (in fact
we have $\frac{n^2}{1681} \gt \frac{(n+1)^2}{1682}$
for $n\geq 3363$).

However (*) is true for the 272 successive integers in the
interval $I=[1546,1816]$ except for $n=1681$. Is there a simple explanation to that
fact ?

I’ve looked at the map $f(n)=\lceil \frac{n^2}{1681}\rceil= 
\lfloor \frac{(n+1)^2}{1682}\rfloor$ for $n\in I\setminus \lbrace 1681\rbrace$. The expression
$f(n+1)-f(n)$ is nearly always equal to $2$, except in a few
erratically placed spots where it is $1$ or $3$.

Maybe $1681=41^2$ plays a role here.

Comment: When $n=1681$, the functions $g(n)=n^2/1681$ and $h(n)=(n+1)^2/1682$ differ by 1 and have equal derivative. Since their second derivatives aren't too different, it's not too surprising that they continue to differ by about 1 over a fairly large interval around 1681, which is more or less the content of your equality. (I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because it doesn't quantify "fairly large"...)

Comment: Isn't $1681\in I$? $\lceil\frac{1681^2}{1681}\rceil = 1681\ne1682=\lfloor\frac{1682^2}{1682}\rfloor$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference (without floor and ceiling) between the two terms is $\frac{n^2-3362n-1681}{2827442}$. The apex of this parabola is at $1681$ and is $-1$ there and under "optimal conditions" for the floor and ceiling to wipe it away not only there, but also at the flat neighbourhood of it.

In fact notictíng that  $$\lceil\frac {n^2}{1681}\rceil-2n+1681=\lceil\frac{(n-1681)^2}{1681}\rceil$$ and $$\lfloor \frac {(n+1)^2}{1682}\rfloor-2n+1681 =\lfloor \frac{(n-1681)^2}{1682}\rfloor +1$$ may make the existence of such a streak more easily visible

Comment: Actually, $41$ *is* a somewhat special number in connection with quadratoic polynomials. I didn't test it numerically, but is the length of the streak significantly different if one replaces $1681$ with $n^2$ and $n\ne 41$?

Comment: No the streak does not look significatively different, but the remote context of my question involved Pell’s equation and $41^2-2(29^2)=1$